# Figuring distribution from percentiles

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, montecarlo

I have a table of data given with 1st, 10th, 20th, 25th, 30th, 40th, 50th, 60th, 70th, 75th, 80th, 90th, and 99th percentiles. For all percentiles above 50, the data behaves as if in a normal distribution. For percentiles below 50, it does not. (This is because, for various reasons, there is an artificial floor as to how low a data point can go.)

Is there a way for me to figure out the distribution? The end goal is to generate random variates using something similar to scipy.stats.norm.rvs so that I can then run a monte carlo from that.

```
    1ST  25TH  50TH  75TH  99TH     ppf 25    cdf 25     ppf 75    cdf 75
0   1.4  16.0  25.5  35.6  60.3  15.407635  0.262746  35.592365  0.750162
1   2.6  15.4  24.9  35.0  58.3  14.807635  0.262746  34.992365  0.750162
2  -0.7  12.3  24.4  36.5  65.9  12.309147  0.249838  36.490853  0.750162
3   1.5  14.1  24.3  35.3  60.9  13.308315  0.265687  35.291685  0.750162
4   0.4  14.3  23.6  33.3  56.9  13.907332  0.258763  33.292668  0.750162
5   0.6  13.3  22.7  32.6  55.7  12.807484  0.260791  32.592516  0.750162
6   1.8  14.5  21.5  29.9  49.1  13.106350  0.286888  29.893650  0.750162
7  -0.7  10.8  21.4  32.3  58.6  10.508240  0.255776  32.291760  0.750162
8   2.3  14.1  21.3  29.7  48.6  12.906350  0.281439  29.693650  0.750162
9   1.1  12.4  21.3  30.6  52.5  12.007030  0.259150  30.592970  0.750162
10  1.9  13.0  21.2  29.9  50.0  12.506577  0.262321  29.893423  0.750162
11 -0.7   9.9  21.1  32.3  59.5   9.908466  0.249838  32.291534  0.750162
12  0.6  12.6  21.1  30.1  52.1  12.106803  0.261900  30.093197  0.750162
13 -2.7  10.7  20.9  32.0  57.6   9.808391  0.267540  31.991609  0.750162
14 -1.9   9.9  20.8  32.4  59.6   9.208769  0.262953  32.391231  0.750162
15  0.2  12.2  20.8  30.2  52.8  11.407106  0.268435  30.192894  0.750162
16 -0.7   9.4  20.7  31.9  59.2   9.508466  0.247927  31.891534  0.750162
17 -0.7   9.7  20.2  30.9  56.8   9.508088  0.253863  30.891912  0.750162
18 -0.7  10.4  20.2  30.5  55.3   9.907786  0.260361  30.492214  0.750162
19 -0.7   9.5  19.8  30.1  55.4   9.507786  0.249838  30.092214  0.750162
20  0.8  11.4  19.7  28.8  49.5  10.606879  0.269060  28.793121  0.750162
21  0.3  11.5  19.7  28.5  50.0  10.906652  0.264682  28.493348  0.750162
22  2.4  12.5  19.1  27.0  44.9  11.205972  0.286403  26.994028  0.750162
23 -2.0   8.7  19.1  30.1  56.0   8.108315  0.261678  30.091685  0.750162
24  0.2  10.7  19.1  27.8  49.2  10.406577  0.257290  27.793423  0.750162
25 -0.7   8.9  18.9  29.4  54.6   8.407937  0.260158  29.392063  0.750162
26  0.3  10.5  18.9  27.9  48.7   9.906803  0.264347  27.893197  0.750162
27  1.0  11.1  18.8  27.1  46.1  10.506274  0.265590  27.093726  0.750162
```

Comment: What does the distribution look like if you plot it?

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you want to know how to create a random distribution of points that adhere to the artificial floor, or are you trying to create a random distribution that is distributed around some mean?

Comment: I want to be able to pick (at random) any percentile 1-99 and return that value. For any percentile 50 and greater, I can do that. For percentiles under 50 I cannot, at least not in a way that conforms with the known percentiles. 

Compounding the issue is, all I have access to are the percentiles, so I'm struggling.